# Can I embed an EJSON object inside another EJSON object?

Tags: meteor

In my app, I composed one coffeescript class inside another (an instance of `class A` includes an array of objects that have instances of `class B` as one of their properties). I then discovered [cmather's video about EJSON](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-create-a-custom-ejson-type) and thought it would be cool to use that with my objects. However, Meteor doesn't seem to deal correctly with EJSON objects that are inside other EJSON objects - the `class A` can be saved to the datastore and, when queried, comes back as a `class A`, but `class B` ends up coming back from the collection as an `Object` rather than a `class B` instance. When I ran some test code, embedded EJSON objects seemed to work at first (after the initial `collection.insert()`), but it returned plain `Object`s or even incorrectly structured objects after refreshing the browser. My theory is that there is some mismatch in the behavior of minimongo and server-side mongo, but there could be other causes.

So, is there a way to embed one EJSON object inside another? Perhaps there is a flaw in my code? Is it just a bad idea? I could just have `class A` instantiate the `class B` items itself in its `constructor`, but it seems like EJSON ought to be able to handle this. If you think this is a bug, I'll be happy to submit an issue on github, but thought I'd check here first.

If you need code to try this out, you can try the code below, which sets up two essentially identical classes, one called `Inner`, and one called `Outer`, and creates an instance of of `Outer` called `outer` that contains an instance of `Inner` as the property `innerHere`. In the console, type `testCollection.insert({outerHere: outer}`. Now, `testCollection.findOne()` may give you an object where the object's `innerHere` property is a proper instance of `Inner`, but if you refresh the browser, the same command may return something different.

If this question is hard to follow, let me know, and I'll try to clarify.

The code to set this up (just make a `.coffee` file in a new project's root):

```
@testCollection = new Meteor.Collection("test")

class @Outer
  constructor: (value) ->
    @value = value
  clone: ->
    new Outer(@value)
  equals: (other) ->
    _.isEqual(@, other)
  typeName: ->
    "Outer"
  toJSONValue: ->
    value: @value


EJSON.addType("Outer", (value)->
  new Outer(value)
)

class @Inner
  constructor: (value) ->
    @value = value
  clone: ->
    new Inner(@value)
  equals: (other) ->
    _.isEqual(@, other)
  typeName: ->
    "Inner"
  toJSONValue: ->
    value: @value


EJSON.addType("Inner", (value)->
  new Inner(value)
)

@outer = new Outer({innerHere: new Inner ("inner value")})
```

Comment: I've posted a pull request to greatly simplify this time of things: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1734

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When EJSON calls toJSONValue of your Outer type, it doesn't recurse into the result to automatically detect inner types. Likewise, in fromJSONValue (the function you're passing to the EJSON.addType method), you're getting a JSON value object (the result of whatever toJSONValue returns) and its up to you to do something with that. To better understand the conversion process, let's walk through an example given your classes.

Let's say we're about to pass an instance of your Outer class over the wire (like as a parameter in a method call).

```
myOuter = new Outer({innerHere: new Inner('inner value')});
```

Meteor will follow steps that are similar to:

```
EJSON.stringify(myOuter) => 
  var jsonValue = EJSON.toJSONValue(myOuter);
  var json = JSON.stringify(jsonValue);
```

The call to EJSON.toJSONValue creates a new object with a $type and $value property. the $value property's value is the result of calling toJSONValue on your object. So jsonValue is an object that looks like this:

```
{
  $type: 'Outer',
  $value: {
    innerHere: {
      value: 'inner value'
    }
  }
}
```

Calling JSON.stringify(jsonValue) results in a JSON string that looks like this:

```
"{"$type":"Outer","$value":{"value":{"innerHere":{"value":"inner value"}}}}"
```

If you want the innerHere property to be an EJSON type, we need to call EJSON.toJSONValue on that object as well (from the Outer's toJSONValue method). For example (in js):

```
Outer.prototype.toJSONValue = function () {
  return {
    value: EJSON.toJSONValue(this.value)
  };
};
```

Now lets say we create a new instance of Outer like this:

```
myOuter = new Outer(new Inner('inner value'));
```

And then we call EJSON.toJSONValue(myOuter):

```
{
  $type: 'Outer',
  $value: {
    value: {
      $type: 'Inner',
      $value: {
        value: 'inner value'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the resulting json string that is sent over the wire looks like this:

```
"{"$type":"Outer","$value":{"value":{"$type":"Inner","$value":{"value":"inner value"}}}}"
```

Okay so now what happens in our fromJSONValue function? We're going to get an object that looks similar to whatever toJSONValue returned. So we need to call EJSON.fromJSONValue on each of the properties that we know to be custom types before passing them to the constructor of Outer. In this example you might do this:

```
EJSON.addType('Outer', function (jsonValue) {
  var inner = EJSON.fromJSONValue(jsonValue.value);
  return new Outer(inner);
});
```

The two methods you can use to test serialization and deserialization are:

```
var serialized = EJSON.stringify(myOuter);
var deserialized = EJSON.parse(serialized); // is the resulting object what you expect?
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very helpful answer! The testing method at the end is a really good idea - looks perfect to TDD EJSON code.